# Why is std::move defined in <type_traits> but not in <utility>?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, stl, move-semantics

The [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) and the [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/move/) say that it's defined in `<utility>`. But my IDE sends me to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits".
Cant't understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard only specifies that `#include <utility>` gives you access to `std::move`. It does not require that definition to physically be present in that header file. The standard library is free to be organized internally as implementers see fit. For example, `<utility>` could consist of only `#include <utility_internal>` (which then contains the actual library implementation) - nothing in the standard forbids this.

**In Microsoft's implementation of the standard library, `<utility>` has an `#include <type_traits>`.** Thus, if you do `#include <utility>`, you will get `std::move`. That's all you should have to care about.